# Cannot get the query good

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make a query for a school project but i cannot figure out how it works.

I probably do something wrong with the inner joins

Here is my problem.

I need to get from each opdracht the material costs and the labor costs

I all ready made a query one for the labor costs and one for the material costs

**labor costs query:**

```
USE [Vakgarage De Haas]

SELECT  o.opdrachtnr, o.kenteken, k.achternaam, CAST((t.uurtarief * op.tijdsduur) AS decimal (10,2)) AS arbeidskosten 
FROM  OpdrachtTaak op 
        INNER JOIN Taak t
        ON op.taaknr = t.taaknr
        INNER JOIN Opdracht o
        ON op.opdrachtnr = o.opdrachtnr
        INNER JOIN auto a
        ON o.kenteken = a.kenteken
        INNER JOIN klant k
        ON a.klantnr = k.klantnr
GROUP BY o.opdrachtnr, o.kenteken, k.achternaam, op.tijdsduur,t.uurtarief
```

**result**:

```
**opdrachtnr**  **kenteken**    **achternaam**  **arbeidskosten**

1           12-JS-PP    Pieterse    20.00
1           12-JS-PP    Pieterse    35.00
2           PP-AD-01    Boer             6.00
3           ZK-PL-42    Boer             NULL
```

**material costs query:**

USE [Vakgarage De Haas]

```
SELECT o.opdrachtnr, o.kenteken, k.achternaam, (art.prijs * oa.aantal) AS Materiaalkosten
FROM OpdrachtArtikel oa
        INNER JOIN Artikel art
        ON oa.artikelnr = art.artikelnr
        INNER JOIN Opdracht o
        ON oa.opdrachtnr = o.opdrachtnr
        INNER JOIN auto a
        ON o.kenteken = a.kenteken
        INNER JOIN klant k
        ON a.klantnr = k.klantnr
GROUP BY o.opdrachtnr, o.kenteken, k.achternaam, art.prijs, oa.aantal
```

**result**:

```
**opdrachtnr    kenteken    achternaam  Materiaalkosten**
1           12-JS-PP    Pieterse    60.00
1           12-JS-PP    Pieterse    110.00
2           PP-AD-01    Boer             12.00
3           ZK-PL-42    Boer            220.00
```

But when I try to combine the two query's
with this query:

```
USE [Vakgarage De Haas]

SELECT o.opdrachtnr, o.kenteken, k.achternaam, CAST((t.uurtarief * ot.tijdsduur) AS decimal (10,2)) AS arbeidskosten, (art.prijs * oa.aantal) AS Materiaalkosten
FROM Opdracht o
        INNER JOIN OpdrachtTaak ot
        ON o.opdrachtnr = ot.opdrachtnr
        INNER JOIN Taak t
        ON ot.taaknr = t.taaknr
        INNER JOIN OpdrachtArtikel oa
        ON o.opdrachtnr = oa.opdrachtnr AND ot.opdrachtnr = oa.opdrachtnr
        INNER JOIN Artikel art
        ON oa.artikelnr = art.artikelnr
        INNER JOIN Auto a
        ON o.kenteken = a.kenteken
        INNER JOIN Klant k
        ON a.klantnr = k.klantnr

GROUP BY o.opdrachtnr, o.kenteken, t.uurtarief, ot.tijdsduur, art.prijs, oa.aantal, k.achternaam
```

This is the result i get:

```
opdrachtnr  kenteken    achternaam  arbeidskosten   Materiaalkosten
1           12-JS-PP    Pieterse    35.00            60.00
1           12-JS-PP    Pieterse    35.00            110.00
1           12-JS-PP    Pieterse    20.00            60.00
1           12-JS-PP    Pieterse    20.00            110.00
2           PP-AD-01    Boer            6.00              12.00
3           ZK-PL-42    Boer            NULL             220.00
```

The result i want is:

```
opdrachtnr  kenteken    achternaam  arbeidskosten   Materiaalkosten
1           12-JS-PP    Pieterse    20.00            60.00
1           12-JS-PP    Pieterse    35.00           110.00
2           PP-AD-01    Boer             6.00            12.00
3           ZK-PL-42    Boer             NULL           220.00
```

Can anybody help me please

Answer (score 0):

Try using a union.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  o.opdrachtnr, o.kenteken, k.achternaam, CAST((t.uurtarief * op.tijdsduur) AS decimal    (10,2)) AS Materiaalkosten 
FROM  OpdrachtTaak op 
    INNER JOIN Taak t
    ON op.taaknr = t.taaknr
    INNER JOIN Opdracht o
    ON op.opdrachtnr = o.opdrachtnr
    INNER JOIN auto a
    ON o.kenteken = a.kenteken
    INNER JOIN klant k
    ON a.klantnr = k.klantnr
GROUP BY o.opdrachtnr, o.kenteken, k.achternaam, op.tijdsduur,t.uurtarief
UNION
SELECT o.opdrachtnr, o.kenteken, k.achternaam, (art.prijs * oa.aantal) AS Materiaalkosten
FROM OpdrachtArtikel oa
    INNER JOIN Artikel art
    ON oa.artikelnr = art.artikelnr
    INNER JOIN Opdracht o
    ON oa.opdrachtnr = o.opdrachtnr
    INNER JOIN auto a
    ON o.kenteken = a.kenteken
    INNER JOIN klant k
    ON a.klantnr = k.klantnr
GROUP BY o.opdrachtnr, o.kenteken, k.achternaam, art.prijs, oa.aantal
) tmp
```

Comment: I tryed it with DISTINCT but i get the same result

Comment: Oh I see what happened.  Have you tried simply "UNION"-ing the two queries together?